# Binding the meta key (a.k.a. super key / Windows key) to left click

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, mouse

How can I bind the meta key (a.k.a. [super key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)) / Windows key) to a left click? Hitting the meta key should trigger a left click, and pressing down on it should allow me to drag and drop (just like it would do when holding down left click).

I tried using System Preferences -> Shortcuts and Gestures:

[image]

but I cannot set "meta" alone as being a shortcut.

I use Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4.

(On Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate I can achieve that using the program [SmartNav](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/support/downloads.html).)

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.